# Stanford Parser: can dependencies be converted to a parse tree?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, nlg

Is there a way to go from dependencies:

```
nmod:poss(dog-2, My-1)
nsubj(likes-4, dog-2)
advmod(likes-4, also-3)
root(ROOT-0, likes-4)
xcomp(likes-4, eating-5)
dobj(eating-5, sausage-6)
```

to the corresponding parse tree?

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog))
    (ADVP (RB also))
    (VP (VBZ likes)
      (S
        (VP (VBG eating)
          (NP (NN sausage)))))
    (. .)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you can only do the translation in the other direction.